# RCurl (or httr) - specifying cert info

Tags: r, rcurl, httr

I've been playing with httr and RCurl for a while and am struggling with specifying some certificate information.

I have a Curl CLI command that works just fine to log me in to a website that uses self-signed certs for authentication (as well as uname/pwd), it looks something like this...

```
curl -k -q -v --cert "../certs/foobar.pem" https://signon.foobar.com/certlogin -d "username=foo&password=bar" -H "X-Application: Curltest"
```

This logs me in to foobar.com and returns a session token.

The same command works if I use the corresponding .crt cert file and add a key using the --key option.

I'm trying to do the same thing with RCurl or httr and keep getting an error that indicates that the cert is wrong. Bearing in mind that I know the cert is OK (as the CLI command works) I assume this is because I'm specifying the cert incorrectly in RCurl.

So, quick question...

How would you reproduce the CURL command given above in RCurl or httr?

BTW this is on Ubuntu - so should not be related to the issues lots of folks are having with Mac OS X 10.9 +

Many thanks

Eluxoso
(first time poster - be nice....!)

Here is my (probably very inelegant & certainly non-functioning) code

RCurl:

```
Library(RCurl)
url <- "https://signon.foobar.com/certlogin"
uname <- "foo"
pswd <-"bar"
headers <- list("X-Application" = "Curltest")
opts=curlOptions(verbose=TRUE, 
                 httpheader=headers, 
                 cainfo="../certs/foobar.pem", 
                 ssl.verifypeer=FALSE)
postForm(url, 
         "username" = uname, "password"=pswd,
         .opts=opts,
         style='POST'
)
```

httr:

```
library(httr)
cafile="../certs/foobar.pem"
resp<-POST("https://signon.foobar.com/certlogin", 
           body = list(username="foo", password = "bar"),
           add_headers("X-Application" = "Curltest" ), 
           verbose(),
           encode = "form",
           config(cainfo = cafile, ssl.verifypeer=FALSE))
content(resp,"text")
```

Having used a full pathname for the cert I still get the same server response, despite the CURL CLI command working.
In the HTTP requests I noticed this:

```
SSL certificate verify result: self signed certificate in certificate chain (19), continuing anyway.
```

Is that relevant/helpful to someone?..

Comment: What did you try in R?

Comment: Updated to include my R code

Comment: You absolutely should not have `ssl.verifypeer=FALSE`

Comment: I'd also try using an absolute path to cafile.

Comment: Agree re: ssl.verifypeer=FALSE  just in there to correspond to the -k in CLI command that is actually working...   won't make the final cut!

Comment: Added a snippet of the HTTP/ssl dialogue

Answer (score 2):

I had [this issue](https://github.com/ropensci/traits/issues/18), and it was resolved by installing `libcurl4-openssl-dev` and updating the `Rcurl` package to the most recent version (1.95)

```
$ sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev
$ R
> install.packages("RCurl")
```